# EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) in iOS 14.2 version

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, ios-app-group

My app currently registered in the App Store works normally in version 14 or earlier, but it does not run after updating to iOS 14.2 version.(The app doesn't launch, waits for a few seconds on a black screen and then closes.)

It would be very much appreciated if you could take a look at the crash log below and tell us about a solution.

Regardless of the model, only the device updated to iOS 14.2 version does not work, and the device updated to iOS 14.2 also works normally when test build with xCode and run.
Only those uploaded to TestFlight and the App Store are causing the problem.

```
**Crash Code**
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog transgression: application<com.Dragonfly.SAPTAR>:583 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.270 (user 6.270, system 0.000), 5% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.274, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6fd5f5c 0x1b6fad000 + 167772
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a357794 0x18a353000 + 18324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3576c0 0x18a353000 + 18112
3   UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd12430 0x18c549000 + 8164400
4   UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd1277c 0x18c549000 + 8165244
5   UIKitCore                       0x000000018ccf9394 0x18c549000 + 8061844
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000018ccf9680 0x18c549000 + 8062592
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecb3c58 0x19ecb2000 + 7256
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecba318 0x19ecb2000 + 33560
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecbb910 0x19ecb2000 + 39184
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecca498 0x19ecb2000 + 99480
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecb4524 0x19ecb2000 + 9508
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd12c80 0x18c549000 + 8166528
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000018c9e605c 0x18c549000 + 4837468
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018c9e68f0 0x18c549000 + 4839664
15  UnityFramework                  0x00000001029d48c4 0x102800000 + 1919172
16  UnityFramework                  0x00000001029d7008 0x102800000 + 1929224
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a7a78 0x18a396000 + 72312
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39884c 0x18a396000 + 10316
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a78a4 0x18a396000 + 71844
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39918c 0x18a396000 + 12684
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a8344 0x18a396000 + 74564
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a7e2c 0x18a396000 + 73260
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a9d14 0x18a396000 + 81172
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39bd44 0x18a396000 + 23876
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a6b8124 0x18a63d000 + 504100
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a687e10 0x18a63d000 + 306704
27  Foundation                      0x000000018b9b7908 0x18b97b000 + 248072
28  SAPTAR                          0x0000000100cb28ec 0x100cac000 + 26860
29  SAPTAR                          0x0000000100cb2994 0x100cac000 + 27028
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3976c0 0x18a396000 + 5824

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6fd5204 0x1b6fad000 + 164356
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8214 0x1d2ed1000 + 29204
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8164 0x1d2ed1000 + 29028
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a9bec 0x18a396000 + 80876
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39bd44 0x18a396000 + 23876
5   SoftLinking                     0x00000001cabb4f50 0x1cabb4000 + 3920
6   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aef8074 0x18ad5e000 + 1679476
7   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aef7fd0 0x18ad5e000 + 1679312
8   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aefc8f0 0x18ad5e000 + 1698032
9   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aefb10c 0x18ad5e000 + 1691916
10  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ae09e60 0x18ad5e000 + 704096
11  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ad69318 0x18ad5e000 + 45848
12  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ae0c36c 0x18ad5e000 + 713580
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a364fb8 0x18a353000 + 73656
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35e10c 0x18a353000 + 45324
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35ec90 0x18a353000 + 48272
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a368d78 0x18a353000 + 89464
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed4804 0x1d2ed1000 + 14340
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2edb75c 0x1d2ed1000 + 42844

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6fd5204 0x1b6fad000 + 164356
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8214 0x1d2ed1000 + 29204
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8164 0x1d2ed1000 + 29028
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a9bec 0x18a396000 + 80876
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39bd44 0x18a396000 + 23876
5   SoftLinking                     0x00000001cabb4f50 0x1cabb4000 + 3920
6   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aef8074 0x18ad5e000 + 1679476
7   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aef7fd0 0x18ad5e000 + 1679312
8   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aefc8f0 0x18ad5e000 + 1698032
9   CFNetwork                       0x000000018aefb10c 0x18ad5e000 + 1691916
10  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ae09e60 0x18ad5e000 + 704096
11  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ad69318 0x18ad5e000 + 45848
12  CFNetwork                       0x000000018ae0c36c 0x18ad5e000 + 713580
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a364fb8 0x18a353000 + 73656
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35e10c 0x18a353000 + 45324
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35ec90 0x18a353000 + 48272
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a368d78 0x18a353000 + 89464
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed4804 0x1d2ed1000 + 14340
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2edb75c 0x1d2ed1000 + 42844

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit.applicationSupportClient
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6fd5204 0x1b6fad000 + 164356
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8214 0x1d2ed1000 + 29204
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8164 0x1d2ed1000 + 29028
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a9bec 0x18a396000 + 80876
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39bd44 0x18a396000 + 23876
5   SoftLinking                     0x00000001cabb4f50 0x1cabb4000 + 3920
6   BoardServices                   0x00000001a35b1160 0x1a359f000 + 74080
7   BoardServices                   0x00000001a35ae720 0x1a359f000 + 63264
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3585c8 0x18a353000 + 21960
10  BoardServices                   0x00000001a35ae398 0x1a359f000 + 62360
11  BoardServices                   0x00000001a35a6924 0x1a359f000 + 31012
12  UIKitServices                   0x000000018e75ca50 0x18e754000 + 35408
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a365428 0x18a353000 + 74792
15  UIKitServices                   0x000000018e75c938 0x18e754000 + 35128
16  UIKitServices                   0x000000018e75c160 0x18e754000 + 33120
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd125b0 0x18c549000 + 8164784
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd124c0 0x18c549000 + 8164544
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd12498 0x18c549000 + 8164504
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3585c8 0x18a353000 + 21960
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd12430 0x18c549000 + 8164400
23  UIKitCore                       0x000000018cd12740 0x18c549000 + 8165184
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35524c 0x18a353000 + 8780
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a367a68 0x18a353000 + 84584
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a368120 0x18a353000 + 86304
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed47c8 0x1d2ed1000 + 14280
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2edb75c 0x1d2ed1000 + 42844

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.GDTCORUploadCoordinator
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b6fd5204 0x1b6fad000 + 164356
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8214 0x1d2ed1000 + 29204
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed8164 0x1d2ed1000 + 29028
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a3a9bec 0x18a396000 + 80876
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a39bd44 0x18a396000 + 23876
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b2676d0 0x18b1f6000 + 464592
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3585c8 0x18a353000 + 21960
8   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b267bd4 0x18b1f6000 + 465876
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3585c8 0x18a353000 + 21960
11  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b5b22fc 0x18b1f6000 + 3916540
12  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b5af218 0x18b1f6000 + 3904024
13  Foundation                      0x000000018bab6604 0x18b97b000 + 1291780
14  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a0a2115c 0x1a0a1f000 + 8540
15  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a0a20908 0x1a0a1f000 + 6408
16  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a0a2d940 0x1a0a1f000 + 59712
17  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b798a80 0x18b1f6000 + 5909120
18  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018b79a8d8 0x18b1f6000 + 5916888
19  SystemConfiguration             0x000000018ac15d64 0x18abeb000 + 175460
20  SystemConfiguration             0x000000018ac15fa8 0x18abeb000 + 176040
21  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3c12c 0x102800000 + 3391788
22  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3bf38 0x102800000 + 3391288
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a3585c8 0x18a353000 + 21960
25  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3bf14 0x102800000 + 3391252
26  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3bec8 0x102800000 + 3391176
27  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecb3c58 0x19ecb2000 + 7256
28  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecba318 0x19ecb2000 + 33560
29  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecbb910 0x19ecb2000 + 39184
30  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecca498 0x19ecb2000 + 99480
31  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ecb4524 0x19ecb2000 + 9508
32  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3e8b4 0x102800000 + 3401908
33  UnityFramework                  0x0000000102b3e38c 0x102800000 + 3400588
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a356db0 0x18a353000 + 15792
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35a12c 0x18a353000 + 28972
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a36bc08 0x18a353000 + 101384
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35dfd8 0x18a353000 + 45016
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a35ec5c 0x18a353000 + 48220
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a368d78 0x18a353000 + 89464
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2ed4804 0x1d2ed1000 + 14340
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2edb75c 0x1d2ed1000 + 42844

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2edb754 0x1d2ed1000 + 42836

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000001b01   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000018a36c1c8   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000023
    x8: 0x0000000000001f07   x9: 0x0000000000001b00  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000000000000000f
   x12: 0x0000000000f84337  x13: 0x03000001e7fde729  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000001e7fde728
   x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x000000018cd12434  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000001e7feff20  x21: 0x0000000001000002  x22: 0x0000000000001b01  x23: 0x0000000000000008
   x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25: 0x00000001e7f83a7c  x26: 0x00000001010ef9a0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f14dec0   lr: 0x000000018a357794
    sp: 0x000000016f14dea0   pc: 0x00000001b6fd5f5c cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: It's an `08badf00d` exception - The watchdog timer expired before your app launched.  This means that it was hung up doing work and didn't return from `didFinishLaunching`.   Symbolicate the crashlog to determine where it crashed. Also, have a look at didFinishLaunching`  code and make sure you aren't doing any large tasks that block the thread there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception.

There was a request for location permission in AppDelegate.swift and it was too much time.

I removed it. I have permissions request in the main().