# how to fix flutter xcode ios EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) exception issue

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

in flutter when i try to run my ios app in release mode,its crashing,but this app is runnung in debug mode successfully,after uploading to testflight and then installing on my iphone ,it automatically crashing and showing this **exception EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT**).if anyone know how to fix this ,plze let me know,thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I have similar problem, crashing on first execution after installing with exception EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL). 
After the first its working OK

Comment: I found the the solution for my exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908431/exc-crash-sigkill-in-ios-14-2-version/73009770#73009770